# How to call a space in which every G$_\kappa$-set is open

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, soft-question, terminology

Recall that in a topological space $X$, we say that a subset $A\subset X$ is a G$_\delta$-set if $A$ is the intersection of countably many open sets of $X$. Also, we say that $X$ is a [$P$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-space#P-spaces_in_the_sense_of_Gillman.E2.80.93Henriksen) if G$_\delta$-sets are open.

Now, call as G$_\kappa$-set the intersection of $\kappa$ many open sets, where $\kappa\geq\aleph_0$ is a cardinal. I would like to know if there is some standard name for those spaces in which G$_\kappa$-sets are open, for a fixed cardinal $\kappa\geq \aleph_0.$

Motivation: this kind of space arose in my PhD thesis, but I do not know any references in which they appear. I'm temporary calling them as $P_\kappa$-spaces.

Comment: Excelent choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sikorski](https://eudml.org/doc/213209) (1950) call these spaces as $\omega_\mu$-additive spaces.